# How to use UWP's WebAccountManager and AccountSettingsPane for an Xbox app?

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api, windows-runtime, xbox

I built an app that runs on Xbox and PCs. I successfully added WebAccountManager and AccountSettingsPane to the app following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager. It works great on my Surface. However, after testing on Xbox, the AccountSettingsPane does not pop up. Does anyone know if Xbox doesn't support this UWP API?

Here is my code for opening the AccountSettingsPane. It works on PCs and tablets, but not Xbox.
[image]

Source: https://github.com/jenius-apps/ambie/blob/de2493109a618aa8723df499c469a6741d20216d/src/AmbientSounds.Uwp/Services/MsaAuthClient.cs#L131-L140

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . However, after testing on Xbox, the AccountSettingsPane does not pop up. Does anyone know if Xbox doesn't support this UWP API?

Please refer [UWP features not supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox#feature-areas-less-applicable-to-xbox) document, `AccountSettingsPane` and `WebAccountCommand` APIs are not supported on Xbox. For login Xbox from UWP app, you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/features/identity/auth/auth-uwp/live-auth-for-uwp-projects).

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! I wish I saw this info directly inside the doc for Web Account Manager. That's okay, I'm just glad this isn't some obscure bug. Thanks again.